# Does $\mathrm{Im}(\exp)$ being a manifold imply the domain is a manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation

Let $G$ be a real matrix group of dimension $n$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote the lie algebra of $G$. Suppose $X \subset \mathfrak{g}$ such that $e^X$ is a submanifold of $G$ of dimension $m$.

Does this imply that $X$ is a subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$ of dimension at least $m$?

Edit: Replace "subspace" by "submanifold".

Thanks!

Comment: Let $X$ be any nonzero point.

Comment: Yes.. Let me rephrase my question and replace "subspace" by "submanifold".

Comment: Let $G = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and let $X = [0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I do not understand: Would you explain how $G$ can be represented as a matrix group?

Comment: I understand now the answer to my last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let $G$ be any connected compact group.  Then $\exp: \mathfrak g \to G$ is onto.  This is a nontrivial statement, but follows from the following argument.  Choose a bi-invariant metric on $G$ (choose any metric, and average for both the left and right actions of $G$); its derivative at the origin is a $G$-invariant metric on $\mathfrak g$, which you can extend to a translation-invariant metric.  Then $\exp$ is distance-preserving when restricted to any line through the origin of $\mathfrak g$.  It follows from the compactness of $G$ that you can choose $r\in \mathbb R_{>0}$ such that, if $B_r$ denotes the ball centered at $0\in \mathfrak g$ of radius $r$, then $\exp : B_r \to G$ is onto.

So let $X = B_r \cup Y$, where $Y \subseteq \mathfrak g \smallsetminus B_r$ is some randoms subset, which is not a manifold.  Then $\exp(X) = G$ is definitely a submanifold of $G$, even though $X$ is not a manifold.  If you want an example where $\exp(X)$ is a proper submanifold, just embed $G$ into a larger compact group, and repeat the argument.

---

You could also ask the following question.  Suppose that $M \looparrowright G$ is an immersed submanifold (or, perhaps, restrict to embedded submanifolds).  Is the full preimage $\exp^{-1}(M)$ a submanifold of $\mathfrak g$?  If $\exp$ were a submersion, the answer would be yes, since pullbacks along submersions always exist in manifolds.  Unfortunately, $\exp$ is not a submersion.

To see this, consider $G = \mathrm{SU}(2) \cong S^3$, with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2) = \mathbb R^3$ with the cross product.  Let $S^2_r \subset \mathbb R^3$ denote the sphere of radius $r$; then $\exp^{-1}(1)$ is a disjoint union of spheres of radius $2\pi n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$.  Draw a curve through the origin.  Its preimage will look like a curve unioned with a bunch of 2-spheres, and so jumps in dimension.